# Mapping API url from different files Swift 4 (ALAMOFIRE)

Tags: swift, api, alamofire

im still new in Swift, i have a problem related to api URL. i have list of API URL where i place in a separate class which is class ServerApi. The reason is because it is easier for me to change the URL if needed since its already place in one file. the code is as below:

```
class ServerApi {

private static let BASE_URL = "http://myurl";

static var API_LOGIN = BASE_URL + "/auth/local";
static var API_SIGNUP = BASE_URL + "/auth/local/register"
static var API_PLACE = BASE_URL + "/place"
static var API_ONE_PLACE = BASE_URL + "/place/%s"
static var API_IMAGE = BASE_URL + "/%s"

private static let URL_PATH = "http://myurl2";

static var URL_CREATE_WALLET = URL_PATH + "/wallet";
static var URL_RELOAD_WALLET = URL_PATH + "/wallet/%s/reload";
static var URL_PAYMENT = URL_PATH + "/wallet/%s/payment";
static var URL_WALLET_ACCOUNT = URL_PATH + "/wallet/%s";
static var URL_USER_TRANSACTION = URL_PATH + "/wallet/%s/transactions";
static var URL_ORDER = URL_PATH + "/orders";
static var URL_CABINET = URL_PATH + "/cabinets/%s";
static var URL_CREATE_PAYMENT = URL_PATH + "/payments";
static var URL_IMAGE = URL_PATH + "/payments";

}
```

`%s` is actually stand for user id, where it is changeable depend on user. i just state as %s because i have no idea what actually it should be. I use Alamofire to return the data. Below is one of the example where i call url that does not need `user_id` which is `%s` in the URL:

```
        Alamofire.request(ServerApi.API_LOGIN, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseJSON { response in


        if (response.result.isSuccess){

            if let value = response.result.value {
                print(value)

                Helper.helper.switchToViewController(Navigation: "mainVC")

                let dataObject:Dictionary = value as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                print(dataObject)

                let balanceObject:String = dataObject["jwt"] as! String
                print ("balance object of jwt is : \(balanceObject)")
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(value: balanceObject, key: "jwt")

                print(UserDefaults.standard.getValue(key: "jwt"))

            } else {}
```

So, if example i want to call `URL_WALLET_ACCOUNT` where its need `user_id (%s)` to complete the url. i dont know how to replace the %s from the url. Below is the previous code before i separate the lis of URL

```
 let user_id = "123456"
 func viewBalance() {

    Alamofire.request ("http://myurl2/wallet/\(user_id)").responseJSON { response in
        print (response)
        if let balanceJSON = response.result.value {

            let dataObject:Dictionary = balanceJSON as! Dictionary<String, Any>
            print(dataObject)

            let balanceObject:Dictionary = dataObject["data"] as! Dictionary<String, Any>
            let balance:String = balanceObject["account_balance_display"] as! String
            let newBalance = balance.dropFirst(2)
            self.balanceLabel.text = "\(newBalance)"
        }
    }
}
```